# distinct primes in a matrix (Putnam problem, December 6 2014)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix that is $r \times s$ . And suppose that it has at least $r + s$ distinct primes among absolute values. How do I show that the rank of $A$ must be at least $2$ . I think this would follow from the definition.of rank.But I can't seem.to prove it . If the rank is less than $2$ then the rows are not linearly independent this there difference must be eventually $1$  meaning the won't be distinct primes. Is that right ?

Comment: Welcome to MathExchange. In the future, please remember to use LaTeX formatting for your posts. It makes it easier for us to read. Here is a tutorial for reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Thank you! :-)

Comment: I think, Column rank is equal to the row rank. For example consider the rows first, if there was 1 linearly independent row, then all distinct r+s primes should be in it, but it makes the column rank greater than r, which contradicts.

Comment: Please give the source for the contest problems you post.  Also, please wait longer before posting Putnam problems.  See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17570/this-years-putnam-exam-2014